# Steam refuses to use nvidia gpu

Tags: steam, hybrid-graphics

I keep installing steam on my hybrid graphics laptop a Dell XPS 7590, and it will run, but games don't boot up correctly. They seem to always use the integrated GPU no matter what I do. Any help is appreciated.
Running Ubuntu 21.04 latest from the downloads section of the Ubuntu website.

Comment: what does `lsmod | grep nvidia` give you?

Comment: ```nvidia_uvm           1040384  0
nvidia_drm             61440  1
nvidia_modeset       1183744  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              34930688  17 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        245760  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   552960  19 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915```

Comment: Please provide additional detail in your initial question (it's easier to read).  You've also not provided your OS & release, and if using a LTS release, which kernel stack you're using (GA or HWE as Ubuntu offers two choices).

Comment: I’ve edited my query. Not sure if it’s LTS or not, but my responses are probably going to be postponed until tomorrow since it is currently 11:30 at my place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo prime-select nvidia` at the command line and pray :-)

See also the other `prime-` commands.

`nvidia-smi` can show some useful configuration data.

Or `inxi -Gx`  (but you probably will need to apt install inxi first for that one).

Take a peek at `/var/log/gpu-manager.log` occasionally to see what it was thinking at the timestamp of that file.

You need to tell it to use the nvidia driver on the actual graphics chip.  You might need to blacklist the nouveau driver and ensure you are not using wayland.  If you are really smart or lucky or persistent you will be able to get "Optimus" working and it will use both chips in harmony (whereby the UHD runs the show but offloads any actual hard work to the nvidia chip).

Comment: Prime select is automatically set to on-demand after the first run of steam and changing it does nothing. Prime-run works fine but using it in launch options of steam makes the game instantly crash. I’m not sure how to blacklist the noveau driver or not use wayland.

Comment: Thank you, after disabling wayland, it started using the nvidia GPU like I set it to do.

Comment: Well done.  There were a lot of variables in there but you found the one that mattered.

Comment: did you just have to set it for on-demand and it automatically worked? or did you had to do something else?

Comment: @Felipe See the first line... nvidia.